# Android: others colors in ListView for item

Tags: java, android

I have a listview.
Task:
make text in some items other colors (black for example by name) when adapter set in Listview  if

```
if myList[i].indexOf("#") != -1
```

Code:

```
    private void doList()
{
    File file = new File(getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/files");
    File[] file_list = file.listFiles();
    myList = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(file_list.length > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < file_list.length; i++)
        {
            myList.add(file_list[i].getName());
        }
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);

    buy_list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You have to implement your own ListAdapter, have a look at this grat tutorial. Especially at Point 3 http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: To do this you need to create your own Adapter !

Answer (score 0):

You should implement your own ArrayAdapter and set color in getView() method of that adapter.

Here is a rich and comprehensive tutorial:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html